# Select tag is disabled when nested state used as values

Tags: reactjs

These are the nested states that i'm using.

```
this.state = {
      district: {distname: "Open this select menu", id: ''},
      date: ''
    }
```

This all are in class component so no need to add **function** before function. and here just the `district.id` is getting its values not the `district.distname`

```
change = e => {
    var district = {...this.state.district}
    district.distname = e.target.name
    district.id = e.target.value
    this.setState({district})
  }
```

when `this.state.district.distname` value assigned to the select element the select tag disables itself.

```
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Example select</Form.Label>
            <Form.Select value={this.state.district.distname} onChange= 
             {this.change}>              {Data.map((data, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={data.ID} name={data.District}> 
               {data.District}</option>
              ))}
            </Form.Select>
          </Form.Group>
```

Please can somebody help me out on this.

Comment: Where is `Form.Select` coming from? Can you give us running code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: What controls whether or not the select is disabled? When you `setState` is looks like you're losing the data value stored in there, you should spread existing state when you update it

Comment: @ZacharyHaber Hi, `Form.Select ` is imported from `import { Form } from '@themesberg/react-bootstrap'`

Comment: @Jayce444 Actually this approch works for updating state for the `district.id` but not for `district.name`

Comment: @KunalRaut hmm not sure why that would be. Are you able to make a basic sandbox with that bootstrap dependency recreating the issue?

Comment: Two things to check: 1) Do you get the value you expect from `e.target.name` 2) try setting state like this `this.setState(district)` (without curly braces).